# How do I set up an external monitor as a screen for Ubuntu in the Windows Subsystem for Linux?

Tags: ubuntu, display, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When I launch a graphics application using Ubuntu, installed on my Windows PC

```
C:\Users\User\>bash
user@PC:/mnt/c/Users/User$ gedit
```

I get the following error message:

```
Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused

(gedit:7828): Gtk-WARNING **: 23:09:59.762: cannot open display:
```

Or

```
C:\Users\User\>bash
user@PC:/mnt/c/Users/User$ kolf
QStandardPaths: XDG_RUNTIME_DIR not set, defaulting to '/tmp/runtime- 
userr'
qt.qpa.screen: QXcbConnection: Could not connect to display
```

Could not connect to any X display.
I've already tried avoiding this by using a screen server host for Windows, however, that instantly crashed as soon as I closed a window. I think this may be because of the fact that it displays the windows on top of the existing Windows interface.

I am now wondering if it may be possible to simply link a second display to Ubuntu, as if it were attached to a Ubuntu-run PC.

Comment: Did you set this `export DISPLAY=:0`? Is there any X-Server running like VcxSrv, Xming, X410 etc?

Comment: I'm sorry for the misunderstanding but using such a display server for the Ubuntu in Windows works perfectly fine. I was asking if there was some program that could dedicated an entire screen to Ubuntu instead of to Windows.